# css issue, nivo controlnav border not appearing

Tags: css, nivo-slider

im working on this site at the moment and and cant figure out why this shouldnt work..
Im looking to put small borders on the bottom and top of each controlnav link (seen on the right of the slides), If anyones got any pointers itd be great...
http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms/

```
.nivo-controlNav a + a {
border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

I will just include a small bit more css for clarity so you can see what im talking about...

```
.nivo-controlNav {
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
right:-180px;
height:474px;
width:180px;
top:0px;
z-index:8;
}

.nivo-controlNav a {
cursor:pointer;
height:68px;
padding: 13px 20px;
width:140px;
display:block;
background: url('http://limerickfc.hailstormcommerce.com/cms/wp-content/themes   /limerickfc/images/slideshowBg.jpg') scroll 0 0 transparent;
background-repeat: repeat-y; 
color: #6ED5FF;

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the attached page using Firebug you have this style declared in your inline stylesheet

```
#slider a {
    border: 0 none;
    display: block;
}
```

If you remove the border: 0 none; line the border will appear, it is currently overriding your NivoControlNav style.

Comment: Hi munnster thanks very much! That sorted it! not sure why I included that border , I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two offending CSS rules

```
.nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}
```

Your selector, `.nivo-controlNav a + a` has slightly more *specificity* than `.nivoSlider a`, so yours should win out.  However, there is also this rule:

```
#slider a {
    border:0 none;
    display:block;
}
```

The ID in this rule gives it much more specificity than yours.  Either remove the `border` property from this rule, or add an ID to your selector to give it more specificity.

More on [CSS selector specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).